# What is the set of independent parameters that can be used to describe a quantum particle like photon or electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, photons

How many independent parameters are there for fully describing a quantum particle like photon or electron?

Comment: This sounds like an exercise. Those two particle are actually very different. What are your own thoughts to this?

Comment: infinitezero- Have no clue

Comment: Maybe you should think about polarization and wavevectors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the complete quantum description of a free electron](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127222/what-is-the-complete-quantum-description-of-a-free-electron)

Comment: I know a few parameters that can be used to describe a quantum particle like energy, spin, momentum and probably this isn't a full set.